# Angular simple view is not loading controller content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written the following script of Angular in scripts.js:

```
// defining a Module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


// defining a controller as the child of the above module
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.authors = [
        { author : "Jack London", book : 'Martin Eden'},
        { author : "Thomas Hardy", book : 'Jude, the Obscure'},
        { author : "Emile Zola", book : 'Germinal'},
    ];

    $scope.addNewAuthor = function(){
        $scope.authors.push = function(){
           author : $scope.newAuthor.name,
           book : $scope.newAuthor.book,
        },
    };
});
```

And then I have written this HTML view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js" ></script>
</head>
<body >
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="myController">
        <ul data-ng-repeat="single in authors">
           Author {{ single.author }} has written {{ author.book }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not work and in view instead of real data I get literally what I have written:

HTML output in browser:

```
Hello

    Author {{ single.author }} has written {{ author.book }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your javascript is wrong. This is not the way to push an item into an `Array`, push must be used as a function :

```
 var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
// defining a controller as the child of the above module
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.authors = [
        { author : "Jack London", book : 'Martin Eden'},
        { author : "Thomas Hardy", book : 'Jude, the Obscure'},
        { author : "Emile Zola", book : 'Germinal'},
    ];

    $scope.addNewAuthor = function(){
        $scope.authors.push({
           author : $scope.newAuthor.name,
           book : $scope.newAuthor.book,
        });
    };
});
```

Also, there is a typo in your HTML, you used author.book instead of single.book :

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="myController">
        <ul data-ng-repeat="single in authors">
           Author {{ single.author }} has written {{ single.book }}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok, I even now removed the push section but it still does not load properly..when I check the files through code inspection in ff I see .js files have been loaded properly

Comment: Great ! I usually put the ng-app on the body rather than the html but I'm not aware of any difference. Please consider accepting the answer if It solved your issue.